# Angular make observable sychronous

Tags: angular

For some models in angular app I want synchronous behavior, where database connector provides Observables which are asynchronous.

I have a service to manage the model. How to implement a `readModel` synchronous? Need to be subscribed to receive values from database or use async-await. Is there a best practice in this scenario?

```
export class Model {
  uid = "";
  name = "";
  set(uid: string, name: string): void {
    //set members
  }  
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ModelService {

  private model = new Model();
  private dbService = inject(DbConnector)   
  
  readModel(uid: string): Model{
    this.dbService.readDocById("models", uid).subscribe((modelData: Model) => {
      this.model.set(modelData.uid, modelData.name);
     // return this.model;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. In your service

```
  readModel(uid: string): Promise<Model> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.dbService.readDocById('models', uid).subscribe(
        (modelData: Model) => {
          this.model.set(modelData.uid, modelData.name);
          resolve(this.model);
        },
        (error) => {
          reject(error);
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

In your component

```
async test(){
const read  = await this.Model.readModel();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't magically make an asynchronous behaviour synchronous.

If it takes time, say 100ms, to read the database then it's asynchronous.

You can turn into promises (doesn't change the fact it's still asynchronous) and block on the main thread by awaiting them but this isn't recommended.

You could expose a BehaviorSubject which components could subscribe to get it's value.

```
  model$ = new BehaviorSubject<Model>(new Model());

  readModel(uid: string) {
    this.dbService.readDocById("models", uid).subscribe((modelData: Model) => {
      // create model object
      this.model$.next(newModel);
    });

    // method has return type void
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the toPromise function of observable is deprecated, so you can use rxjs like this in read model function

```
const data = await firstValueFrom(this.dbService.readDocById("models", uid));
```

Then you can do:

```
const result = await this.readModel(uid);
```